# Quadratic Programming Problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Given the quadratic programming problem
\begin{align*}
min \quad 0.5(x_1-a)^2+0.5(x_2-b)^2+0.5(x_3-c)^2\\
s.t \quad 4x_1+5x_2=20\\
8x_1+3x_2+12x_3=24
\end{align*}
Use the method of projection to obtain analytically the optimal solution in terms of $a,b,$ and $c$.

Can anyone help me how to figure this out? Any help or even a hint is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwjisMCg6bHiAhUix4UKHfyaBJUQFjAEegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusers.jyu.fi%2F~jhaka%2Fopt%2FTIES483_constrained_direct1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Y2rIKFelH4rK10STrrWSB

Comment: WA says this here $$\left\{\frac{1}{836} \left(193 a^2+360 a b+210 a c-1580
   a+274 b^2-168 b c-2080 b+369 c^2+180
   c+4100\right),\left\{\text{x1}\to \frac{5}{418} (45
   a-36 b-21 c+158),\text{x2}\to \frac{1}{5}
   \left(20-\frac{10}{209} (45 a-36 b-21
   c+158)\right),\text{x3}\to \frac{1}{12}
   \left(-\frac{3}{5} \left(20-\frac{10}{209} (45 a-36
   b-21 c+158)\right)-\frac{20}{209} (45 a-36 b-21
   c+158)+20\right)\right\}\right\}$$